# Typechecking path tuples against nested interface

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that represents form values. The interface will be passed as generic arg so it's not static. I guess I would just codegen it otherwise.

```
interface IValues {
  name: string
  nested: {
    array: string[]
    deeply: {
      value: number
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to type check tuples that specify path into such an object.

For example, these would pass

```
['nested', 'array', 0]
['nested', 'deeply', 'value']
```

It's definitely long shot and I don't even have an idea where to start. My guess is mapped types, but I am even confused about those :)

Comment: Are your tuples randomly mixed, or is there a pattern?

Comment: Not sure I understand. User needs to specify path into that object structure. The examples I've shown reflect the interface above.

Comment: I think I don't understand the problem :D - I thought about tuples such as `[string, string, ...number]` - but that's something completely different topic I guess

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for a duplicate, seems like that would be a viable solution. Do you want to make it as an actual answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but i think that example can help you:

[Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDU4BsCuEDOyA3gLABQyyIcAthAFzL5hSgDm5lIBkAJo6QqVkcKFDgBPRs1Yg2AbQC6nYbwgQADlinEVw5ADdseRiBw0ARtD3IAvivtlH5MBI0oAClAD2Gj3DAACwAeABUAGmQPZAgAD0gQXkIAawgJbxhkUIA+ZABeZHkPSNCixUUAbnIsCDBkDQBGOEYvX38g4IxjAkiAImo6XtyC+X7aCF6+gClvQJBeyura+oaLFp8-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-r8chf44c++FvtQBhERoJEyOwDw-qucAgBI9FAbovxOOQSbIN4pxELYIiEFm+BMexZ7jpEmqHOWAq3Fy35KOuFTIAA9B5yAAPIANLkFZ3Q2aW9kLLZdHuV5MRiN4UCBVBuwhXZrL8vmzmRAalHIJ8thuZ53n+QlHFJd4tk5g56WFt04U5fl0VFWQQA)

Comment: you can also take a look to this feature: [Variadic Types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453)

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting, but in theory, the object interface can be indefinitely nested. I suppose it's not possible to do it dynamically?

Comment: Yes, is not possible to do it dynamically until this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453